# Interpretation of four plots returned by lm in R

Tags: regression, residuals

Below are the residuals plot of a linear model in R.

For me, the top left plot is to see if the homoskedasticity hypothesis is verified.
The QQ-plot in the top-right location is to check if the normality of the errors is verified.

However, I don't really understand the use of the two bottom plots, what is their use?
[image: Residuals plot in R]